# Excel 2010 columns contain more than one number, need to sum all numbers within the column from multiple rows

Tags: excel

Need to SUM Excel columns where 1 row has several numbers within one column

```
      Column B
Row1   68
       136
       68
Row2   1394
       931
        33
        33
Row3   33
       420
       350
       250
```

SUM B1:B3 only SUMs first number in cell ?? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I see no straightforward way to accomplish this.

However, you may flatten the cells into individual values. 
Parallel to each cell, issue the formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(10), ",")
```

This will make each cell comma separated. Your row one will become

```
68,136,68
```

You may then employ text to columns under the Data ribbon using the comma delimiter to give each number its own cell.

Thereafter you may rearrange the numbers and issue your SUM.

Answer (score 0):

1] In C1 and copied down to suit:

```
="="&SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(10),"+")
```

2] Copy ColumnC and Paste Special..., Values over the top, Replace All `=` with `=`.

Comment: Had to use = + during replace (not = . ), worked after that!